# browserify without sourcemaps

Tags: node.js, browserify

I'm using Browserify programmatically, through node, like so:

```
var options = {
   debug: true,
   cache: {}, 
   packageCache: {}, 
   fullPaths: true,
   noParse: []
};
var b = browserify( 'index.js', options );
b.on('data', customFunction);
b.bundle();
```

My customFunction doesn't modify the data anyhow, just reads it.
It runs a regex on the first line, to detect the file name of the code that comes on the following lines.

The thing is, when i set options.debug to false, to get rid of the sourcemaps, the customFunction behaves in a very different way (the regex doesn't get half the file names) and i can't seem to figure out the pattern for that difference. I assume that turning debug to false, does more than turning off the sourcemaps.
I just want to turn off the sourcemaps on browserify, with no other side-effects, is this possible?

Comment: i don't know about any side-effects of the `debug` option. Could the function be the problem?

Comment: i updated with more info on the custom function

Comment: i could help you better, when i see the code.

Comment: https://github.com/vigour-io/smapify/blob/master/index.js , customFunction = smapify.buildMaps.
In the end, smapify.smaps is very different, it has a lot less key/value pairs

Answer (score 0):

You could try to extract the source maps with a separate tool like exorcist https://github.com/thlorenz/exorcist